# How to know the QTreeView item decoration is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'm trying to know when the user selects the decoration of an item, because I was trying to implement a single click expand/collapse QTreeview and the decoration now does nothing. It doesn't expand or collapse the item where as if I click on the item it works properly.

```
void MyTreeView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QTreeView::mousePressEvent(event);

    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        QModelIndex index = indexAt(event->pos());

        isExpanded(index) ? collapse(index) : expand(index);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the decoration is selected, it enters the if condition. If it was not, everything works fine.

I don't know if I have to block the decoration action or have a condition in the if statement.

How do I know the decoration is selected and not the item itself or how do I block decoration action ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check when the icon is clicked ?

Comment: The triangle on the left describing an item with children. Clicking on it expands the item and shows the children.
I want to know then this thing is clicked, because for now when it is, it gives me the index of the item and I have no way of knowing from where comes the mouse press event. So it does expand and collapse or collapse and expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
void MyTreeView::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* aEvent )
{
    QModelIndex index = indexAt( aEvent->pos() );

    if ( index.isValid() )
    {
        const bool wasExpanded = isExpanded( index );

        QTreeView::mousePressEvent( aEvent );

        if ( aEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
        {
            const bool expanded = isExpanded( index );

            // QTreeView did not change the item's state ... but you want.
            if ( wasExpanded == expanded )
            {
                expanded ? collapse( index ) : expand( index );
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QTreeView::mousePressEvent( aEvent );
    }
}
```